# Preview does not accurately represent code

Tags: support, editing, preview

`<pre>` tags are lined up with my bullet indents in the code preview, but not in the answer.

[image]

Comment: Any reason why you're using `<pre>` instead of backticks(``)?

Comment: I think this has been asked before and the fix was to use Markdown approved markup

Comment: I figured out a solution: using <ul> and <li> to nest things. I've never used backticks on this site before. do they do the same thing as <pre>?

Comment: @Senoculus For a single line, yes, they do. Also, It's preferred to use Markdown formatting

Comment: also, please keep the question and answer separate @Senoculus. Use the answers section for your answer

Comment: @Sathya Thanks for the feedback. I was using <pre> tags because it puts a blue line on the left margin. Backticks do not provide enough differentiation between normal text and code.

Comment: well, +1 for the awesome screenshot in the post :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Indent 8 spaces if you want code inside bulleted lists.

See https://superuser.com/editing-help for details.

Comment: This solves my problem as far as usability goes, so I'll accept your answer, but I still don't know why the preview would differ from the actual post.

Answer (score -1):

### **Using Nested `<ul>` and `<li>` tags:**

**Code:**

```
<ul>
    <li>bullet 1
        <pre>code 1</pre>
        <ul>
            <li>subpoint 2
                <pre>code 2</pre>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Result:**

- bullet 1

  ```
  code 1
  ```

  - subpoint 2

    ```
    code 2
    ```

### **Using Markdown Formatting:**

**Code:**

```
- bullet 1
    <pre>code 1</pre>
 - bullet 2
        <pre>code2</pre>
```

**Result:**

- bullet 1

  ```
  code 1
  ```

  - bullet 2

    ```
    code2
    ```