# Code block not working

Tags: support, formatting

The code block in this question's [answer by Bruce](https://superuser.com/a/547728/4377) doesn't seem to want to be working.

This is the result (even after highlighting the text and explicitly clicking the code block button.

[image: Faulty Code Blocks]

Comment: I did go ahead and submit the edit, as it had some other things that needed to be changed as well.

Comment: Also, this is a duplicate of [this](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3007/preview-does-not-accurately-represent-code?rq=1), even though the linked thread isn't marked as such. Didn't find it when searching..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to indent by an additional four spaces for code blocks to be considered so under list item.

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: A single indendation level just makes the block part of the preceding list item. If it were a numbered list, Sathya's screenshot would show two "1." items, as the first block breaks the list (due to missing indentation). Indenting it once would fix that: [Broken list](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rt73K.png), [Fixed list](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HhxK0.png).

Comment: I fixed the first one just using normal backquotes; that's why it is how it is. Thanks for the answer, @Sathya!